# body-parser : how to handle a '&' received in a node request?

Tags: node.js, json, body-parser

When I send data to my nodeJS app, I have an issue with the '&' charactere.

If I send this request :

```
var str = JSON.stringify({ myValue: 'hello&world' });
fetch(myAPIpath, {
  method: 'post',
  body: `values=${str}`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
});
```

And I parse the request in my Node app with :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I have the following error :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Indeed, when I log req.body.values I have this :

> {"values":"hello

Do you know how to solve this issue ? Does it mean that I can't send the '&' character in my body request ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally & is a special character with HTML encoding of &amp. To account for this escape the special character via . For example here send \&. You can also see this when you would like to send thing in quotes inside of a request as well.